# Why can I see Two cplex solvers in cp.installed_solvers() when using cvxpy?

Tags: cplex, cvxpy

This is the result.

```
import cvxpy as cp
In [7]: cp.installed_solvers()
Out[7]: ['ECOS', 'ECOS_BB', 'SCS', 'CPLEX', 'OSQP', 'CPLEX']
```

Why do I have two cplex? Is this because one for Cplex.mp and one for Cplex.cp? If this is true, how can I specify which solver to use?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the behavior you described and this looks like a minor bug in cvxpy. I've created an issue in github for this [here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/719). From the looks of it, though, it is harmless. Depending on the type of the problem (QP, MIP, etc.), the correct solver should get selected.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have two copies of CPLEX Optimization Studio (e.g. two different versions) on your machine, that CVXPY can find?

Comment: I can be sure that there is only 1 version of Cplex in my computer, that is CPLEX12.8.